# MySql Connectors 6.7.4 on a medium trust shared environment

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, security

first of all, I would like to say that I have tried to resolve this issue for several hours through trying a bunch of different approaches from people that had the same issues, but to no avail. I am pretty clueless at this point.

I am using MySql.Data and MySql.Data.Entity dlls (version 6.7.4) which I have referenced in my ASP.NET 4.5 application.

I have managed to connect (locally) to my database and query it without a problem.

```
SqlConnection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;User Id=;Password=;database=;");
```

The problem is within a medium trust shared environment.
I get the following error (when attempting to connect to the database):

**Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file. 
Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.**

I have also tried to add "Integrated Security=True;includesecurityasserts=true;autoenlist=false;" to the connection string, but didn't help.

I have also tried to add this in my web.config:

```
<mscorlib>
<security>
  <policy>
    <PolicyLevel version="1">
      <SecurityClasses>
        <SecurityClass Name="MySqlClientPermission" Description="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientPermission, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
      </SecurityClasses>
      <NamedPermissionSets>
        <PermissionSet class="NamedPermissionSet" version="1" Name="ASP.Net">
          <IPermission class="MySqlClientPermission" version="1" Unrestricted="true">
          </IPermission>
        </PermissionSet>
      </NamedPermissionSets>
    </PolicyLevel>
  </policy>
</security>
```

But that did not work either.

I have then tried to add a bunch of PermissionSets, IPermissions and what not in the web.config by following some articles, but that didn't seem to work for me.

Please note:

- Setting trust level="Full" in the web.config is not an option.
- The connection string that I use to connect to the database is not in my web.config, and  I would like to keep it that way.
- Using anything else than MySql is not an option.

Any and all help is appreciated! Thank you!

**EDIT**

I have changed the way I communicate with the database with an ODBC connection.
Works properly using full trust, but as soon as I change to medium trust, I get basically the same error as with MySql connectors.

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction, such as a full example on how you managed to make it work, because I can't seem to make this work using medium trust...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using an ODBC connection.

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase; User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;
```

http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-odbc-5-1/remote-database/

Answer (score 1):

I know you tried the following solution:

1. Change the security from the web config to full trust.
2. Use the bin deployment (Copy to Local for dll property).
3. Change the trust level from   assembly. 
   and so many other but no one is working.

you can not deploy this on medium trust. It required full trust for proper working.
May be you are using the medium trust server for deployment. You need full trust for the deployment. Only solution is you need to run it on Full trust environment. You need to contact with your server support and change the trust level medium to Full.

Comment: That is not an option. I am on a shared hosting environment and they will not upgrade the trust to full. There **has** to be a way to make this work...

Comment: If you are using go daddy they provide Trust level full on  .net 3.5 and upper version.

One more solution is you need to use ODBC connection. It is only possible if you are not using entity framework.

Comment: I am with HostGator and they will not raise trust to Full, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: I faced same problem with HostGator. We tried with ODBC connection and it worked for me.

Comment: Looks like I will have to go with an ODBC connection then! I will try that tonight and post back here, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved a similar issue with trying to get MySql to work in a medium trust environment.

We tried everything to the ‘book’ and simply could not get it to work!

Turns out the MySql connecter version is the key. **Ask you web hosting company what version of the MySqlClient they have installed on their server in GAC**.

*(GAC simply means the library is installed on the server so that it can be referenced directly and without you having to upload the MySql.Data.dll to your bin folder. The latest installable version is available here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).*

Once the driver is installed on the server in GAC you just need to reference it in your web.config like this, but **replace Version=6.6.5.0 with your web hosting companies version**:

> ```
> <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
>   <assemblies>
>     <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
>   </assemblies>    
> </compilation>
> ```